how does ssh service know where the configuration is?
This is the service unit file:
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service

So how is it specified here where the config file (normally /etc/ssh/sshd_config) is located?
Ok, I found from the manual pages:

-f config_file
Specifies the name of the configuration file.  The default is /etc/ssh/sshd_config.  sshd refuses to start if there is no configuration file.

but how are the options passed if I want to override in this case ?

"Default" in this case means it is defined at the source code level - specifically in pathnames.h

Assuming you want to specify a different config file, pass the -f option and the location of the file.
Source: man sshd (oddly the answer is found in the same paragraph you quoted from)
   -f config_file
             Specifies the name of the configuration file.  The default is
             /etc/ssh/sshd_config.  sshd refuses to start if there is no con‐
             figuration file.

